# Modifying TYPO3 form.checkbox hiddenfield

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

When the following code is added to a partial HTML class in TYPO3.

```
<f:form.checkbox id="myCheckBox" property="myCheckBox" value="Y" multiple="no"  />
```

When the form is loaded within a TYPO3 extension the following code is generated for the checkbox

```
 <input type="hidden" name="form[newForm][myCheckBox]" value="" />
 <input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="form[newForm][myCheckBox]" value="Yes" />
```

Is there a way of adding the parameter ID to the auto generated hidden field so we have:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="myCheckBoxHidden" name="form[newForm][myCheckBox]" value="" />
 <input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="form[newForm][myCheckBox]" value="Yes" />
```

Using TYPO3 7.6.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could extend the `CheckboxViewHelper` and add the `id` attribute as you needed, and then use your new VH instead.

Comment: thanks @bill for the idea, have created a ViewHelper in the extension  that extends the class as suggested !